# WP7 WCF The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, .net-4.0

I have started recieving this error in my WCF service for reasons I cannot comprehend:
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at IPublicService.GetProduct(String barcode)
>   at PublicServiceClient.GetProduct(String barcode)
>
> Inner Exception: The underlying connection was closed: The connection
>   was closed unexpectedly.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)

Here is the service method:

```
public Product GetProduct(string barcode)
        {
            DataContext Db = new DataContext();
            var p = Db.Products.Find(barcode);
            if (p == null)
                return null;

            return new Product()
            {
                ProductID = p.ProductID,
                Name = p.Name,
                Nutrition = p.Nutrition,
                Allergen = p.Allergen,
                Image = p.Image,
                ManufacturerID = p.ManufacturerID,
                ReviewIDs = p.ReviewIDs
            };
        }
```

Here is the Product data contract:

```
[DataContract]
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [DataMember]
        public string ProductID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataMember]
        public string Nutrition { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataMember]
        public string Allergen { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataMember]
        public string Image { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Manufacturer ManufacturerID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Review> ReviewIDs { get; set; }
    }
```

However if I change the service method to this:

```
public Product GetProduct(string barcode)
        {
            DataContext Db = new DataContext();
            var p = Db.Products.Find(barcode);
            if (p == null)
                return null;

            //return new Product()
            //{
            //    ProductID = p.ProductID,
            //    Name = p.Name,
            //    Nutrition = p.Nutrition,
            //    Allergen = p.Allergen,
            //    Image = p.Image,
            //    ManufacturerID = p.ManufacturerID,
            //    ReviewIDs = p.ReviewIDs
            //};
            return new Product();
        }
```

No exception is thrown and it returns and empty product, so I am not sure what is causing the ambiguous exception I am getting, can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Are you sure none of the members violate any of the WCF limits (max string length, max message size)?

Comment: @Chris - Do you know what those limits are? I imagine the Image is causing the failure (timeout, size, etc..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the WCF exceptions are not always very helpful but it is likely that you run into some of the inbuilt WCF limits (which are tunable). The default [`MaxReceivedMessageSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731078.aspx) is 64kb and the default maximum string length is 8kb I think. Try increasing those limits should fix your problems.

Comment: Yeah the list of reviews was too big... I had to implement them as a seperate API function that returns 10 at a time.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should use the [Svctraceviewer.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) provided by Microsoft for debugging the WCF pluming.  You should run a trace on the service side.